# Error from catch is not defined when debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, async-await

I have a promise that is rejected with an error and I'm using `try`/`catch` to handle it.

```
const foo = async () => {
  try {
    await request();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    debugger;
  }
};
```

When debugging, the `console.log` shows the correct error but if I pass the mouse over it shows that `error` is not defined.

[image]

Why this is happening?

This is making the debugging of errors really hard.

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-wescoff-362gh)

Comment: I can't help but notice that, when I open the debugger on your example, the `error` in the `catch ()` is undefined, but `error` in `error.message` shows correctly. Odd.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown Yes, I notice that, really weird

Answer (score 1):

My workarround is to assign the error to a variable, it is possible to debug this variable.

```
const foo = async () => {
  try {
    await request();
  } catch (error) {
    let myError = error; // <--myError is visible in the debugger!!!    
    console.log(error.message);
    debugger;
  }
};
```